# C# Winform LiveCharts does not know how to plot

Tags: c#, database, wpf, forms, livecharts

I'm trying to draw a graph with some arrays. I got 4 arrays (Time,Temprature,Speed,Water).
I want to add Time array on AxisX. The others are going to be on AxisY. But when I try to draw the graph, I get this error message " C# form livecharts does not know how to plot int32[].."

```cs
cartesianChart2.Series = new LiveCharts.SeriesCollection
            {

                new LineSeries
                {
                    Title="Temprature",
                    Values=new ChartValues<int[]>{Temprature}
                },
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Title="Water",
                    Values=new ChartValues<int[]>{waterGrap}
                },
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Title="Speed",
                    Values=new ChartValues<int[]>{RPMGraph}
                }
            };
```

If you want I can share my code.

Comment: i cannot believe the error message is from the chart library.

Comment: LiveCharts.Helpers.LiveChartsException: 'LiveCharts does not know how to plot Int32[], you can either, use an already configured type or configure this type you are trying to use, For more info see http://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Types%20and%20Configuration

That's error message

Comment: makes sense now.

Comment: Can u give any idea for solve my issue ?

Comment: i'm not familiar with that lib, but what if you change `int[]` to `int` or `double`?

Comment: i tried string but it wasnt work.Gave me 
"C# form livecharts does not know how to plot string[].. "exception message

Comment: İf i write 
 new LineSeries
            {
                Title="Speed",
                Values=new ChartValues<int>{1,2,3,..}
            }
its work but i dont know how can i pass my array into <int>{}

Comment: i did some search, could you try `Values = RPMGraph.AsChartValues()`

Comment: @LeiYang i need help about update the charts values .. can u give me a hand ?